# getView cannot display all items of list - android

Tags: android, getview

I've override a ArrayAdapter to display books info stored in the database. and following is the ViewHolderAdapter:

```
public class ViewHolderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book>
{
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<Book> books;
    private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;

    public ViewHolderAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Book> books) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, books);
        mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.books = books;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cart_row_title);
            holder.authors = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cart_row_author);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Book book = books.get(position);

        holder.title.setText(book.getTitle());
        Log.d("book size", books.size() + "");
        Log.d("book title", book.getTitle());
        .
        .
        .
        return convertView;
    }

    public void updateList(ArrayList<Book> shoppingCart)
    {
        books = shoppingCart;
        Log.d("last book", books.get(books.size()-1).getTitle() + "");
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
}
```

The issue is that when I `updateList`, the list does not change. But in the LogCat:

> 02-06 05:30:43.375 29052-29052/? D/book size: 8
>
> 02-06 05:30:43.375 29052-29052/? D/book title: morning
>
> 02-06 05:30:43.375 29052-29052/? D/book size: 8
>
> 02-06 05:30:43.375 29052-29052/? D/book title: night
>
> 02-06 05:30:43.375 29052-29052/? D/book size: 8
>
> 02-06 05:30:43.375 29052-29052/? D/book title: nice
>
> 02-06 05:30:43.376 29052-29052/? D/book size: 8
>
> 02-06 05:30:43.376 29052-29052/? D/book title: very nice
>
> 02-06 05:30:43.376 29052-29052/? D/book size: 8
>
> 02-06 05:30:43.376 29052-29052/? D/book title: nidaye
>
> 02-06 05:30:43.376 29052-29052/? D/book size: 8
>
> 02-06 05:30:43.376 29052-29052/? D/book title: nima
>
> 02-06 05:30:43.376 29052-29052/? D/book size: 8
>
> 02-06 05:30:43.376 29052-29052/? D/book title: dfd

The `book size` of the book object is 8, but the `book title` just display the first seven books, not including the last no which I added. I think the problem maybe lay in `position`. But cannot figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of books = shoppingCart; use books.clear(); books.addAll(shoppingCart)

Comment: @Luksprog yeah, this method works.